# DequeueReusableCell in Monotouch causes cells to rearrange when scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I am using the Monotouch.Dialog class to populate a `UITableView`. I am using a custom cell and as you can see the code in the Element that gets the cell is as follows:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tv)
{
var cell = tv.DequeueReusableCell(_key) as FoodItemCell;

if (cell == null)
   cell = new FoodItemCell(_foodItem, _key);
else
   cell.UpdateCell(_foodItem);

return cell;
}
```

I got this code from a Miguel De Icaza post online that suggest the proper way to create custom cells for the MonoTouch.Dialog.

The Data is displayed appropriately but when I have a long list and I scroll up and down quickly, the cells swap places in a random unpredictable fashion. So the cell in row in may end up in row 4 when I am finished scrolling.

When I use the following code this problem is solved but as you can see I am not dequeueing cells and this may create memory issues.

```
private FoodItemCell _currentCell;

public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tv)
{
    if(_currentCell == null)
    {
        _currentCell = new FoodItemCell(_foodItem, _key);
        return _currentCell;
    }
    else
    {
        return _currentCell;
    }
}
```

Here is the full code:

```
public class FoodItemElement: Element
{
    private static NSString _key = new NSString ("foodItemCell");
    private FoodItem _foodItem;
    public event EventHandler<ElementClickedEventArgs> ElementClicked;


    public FoodItemElement(FoodItem foodItem): base(null)
    {
        _foodItem = foodItem;
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tv)
    {
        var cell = tv.DequeueReusableCell(_key) as FoodItemCell;

        if (cell == null)
            cell = new FoodItemCell(_foodItem, _key);
        else
            cell.UpdateCell(_foodItem);

        return cell;
    }
}


public class FoodItemCell: UITableViewCell
{    
    private FoodItemCellDataView _dataView;
    private FoodItem _foodItem;

    public FoodItemCell(FoodItem data, NSString key) : base (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, key)
    {
        _foodItem = (FoodItem)data;
        _dataView = new FoodItemCellDataView(_foodItem);

        ContentView.Add(_dataView);
        ConstructCell();
    }

    public override void LayoutSubviews ()
    {
        base.LayoutSubviews ();
        _dataView.Frame = ContentView.Bounds;
        _dataView.SetNeedsDisplay ();
    }

     /// <summary>
     /// Updates the cell.
     /// </summary>
    public void UpdateCell(FoodItem newData)
    {
        _dataView.Update(newData);
        SetNeedsLayout();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructs the cell.
    /// </summary>
    private void ConstructCell()
    {
        //This prevents the default blue color when selecting the cell.
        //this.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
        //this.ContentView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;

        var lblFoodItemName = new UILabel();
        lblFoodItemName.Frame = new System.Drawing.RectangleF(4,2,270,20);
        lblFoodItemName.TextColor = UIColor.Black;
        lblFoodItemName.Font = Fonts.H3;
        lblFoodItemName.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
        lblFoodItemName.Text = _foodItem.Name;

        var lblCalories = new UILabel();
        lblCalories.Frame = new System.Drawing.RectangleF(15,22,75,20);
        lblCalories.TextColor = UIColor.Black;
        lblCalories.Font = Fonts.Small;
        lblCalories.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
        lblCalories.Text = "CAL - " + _foodItem.CaloriesRounded.ToString();

        var lblPortion = new UILabel();
        lblPortion.Frame = new System.Drawing.RectangleF(95,22,190,20);
        lblPortion.TextColor = UIColor.Black;
        lblPortion.Font = Fonts.Small;
        lblPortion.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
        lblPortion.Text = "Portion - " + _foodItem.Portion.ToString();

        this.ContentView.AddSubview(lblFoodItemName);
        this.ContentView.AddSubview(lblCalories);
        this.ContentView.AddSubview(lblPortion);

        Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator;
    }   
}


// I create a view that renders my data, as this allows me to reuse
// the data rendering outside of a UITableViewCell context as well.
public class FoodItemCellDataView : UIView {

     public FoodItemCellDataView(FoodItem foodItem)
     {
          Update (foodItem);
     }

     // Public method, that allows the code to externally update
     // what we are rendering.   
     public void Update(FoodItem foodItem)
     {
          SetNeedsDisplay();
     }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can properly dequeue the cells and not have the scrolling issue?

Comment: It looks like reusing does not work properly (e.g. things are not updated for either new, or reused, cells). Can you show us (edit your question) your code for `UpdateCell` and how `_key` is defined (the .ctor could prove useful too).

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not show what _dataView.Update(newData) does, but I am usuming it doesn't change anything on the cell layout, but just refreshes the UI elements with new data. In that case (and I must be mad to contradict Miguel), you should be calling cell.UpdateCell(_foodItem) with every visit to GetCell whether the cell is dequeued or new, so:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tv)
{
var cell = tv.DequeueReusableCell(_key) as FoodItemCell;

if (cell == null)
   cell = new FoodItemCell(_foodItem, _key);
// else  <- I would remove this
   cell.UpdateCell(_foodItem);

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to be sure why without seeing more source code (see my comment).

Here's a working example ([BubbleCell](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/blob/master/BubbleCell/BubbleCell/Bubble.cs)) that you can use to compare your code with.

One important part is to call [`SetNeedsLayout`](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/blob/master/BubbleCell/BubbleCell/Bubble.cs#L79) in your `UpdateCell` method. Otherwise the *old* content might appear (in the new reused cell) before a refresh is done. That could explain your issue.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the reply. I believe I am doing what you are suggesting. Please look at the complete code above. I updated the original post.